# string of integers to a list of intergers

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I'd like to convert a list like this `['7,8,9']`into `[7,8,9]` in python. Any ideas on how to do this?
I've tried using for-loops but no success

Thanks

Comment: Add your attempt to the question. The problem is trivial: extract the first element, split, convert to `int` in a list comprehension.

Comment: What should the list `['4,5,6', '7,8,9']` be converted into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
i = ['7,8,9', '4,5,6,7,8']

nums = []
for string_elem in i:
    [nums.append(int(num)) for num in string_elem.split(',')]


print(nums)
# Output
# [7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over loop

```
b = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
      if j ==',':
          continue
      else:
        b.append(int(j))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one element in the original list, like in your example, you can use this one-liner:

```
>>> orig = ['7,8,9']

>>> result = list(map(int, orig[0].split(',')))

>>> print(result)
[7, 8, 9]
```